# MariaDB view with subquery

Tags: sql, mariadb

for a assignment at our university I should create a view against a database, but with the constraint, that it should be only one statement.
And that one statement part is giving me headaches right now.

I've created this statement:

```
CREATE VIEW overbook_future_flights AS
SELECT 
    FlightNo,
    DepartureDateAndTimeUTC,
    ICAO_Code_Origin,
    ICAO_Code_Destination,
    PlaneID,
    NoOfSeats,
    NoOfReservedSeats AS NoReservedSeats
FROM (
    SELECT
        flightexecution.ICAO_Code_Origin,
        flightexecution.ICAO_Code_Destination,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS nowUTC,
        SUM(NoReservedSeats) AS NoOfReservedSeats,
        flightexecution.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC,
        reservation.FlightNo,
        plane.PlaneID,
        plane.NoOfSeats
    FROM reservation
    INNER JOIN flightexecution ON
        flightexecution.FlightNo = reservation.FlightNo AND
        flightexecution.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC = reservation.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC
    INNER JOIN plane ON
        flightexecution.PlaneID = plane.PlaneID
    GROUP BY
        FlightNo,
        DepartureDateAndTimeUTC
    HAVING
        NoOfreservedSeats > NoOfSeats and
        nowUTC < DepartureDateAndTimeUTC
) AS a;
```

But it fails because `create view` does not allow subqueries within the `from` statement.
Normally I would just create multiple views and use the view instead of the subquery, but it should be only one statement.

Does anyone know if this assignment is even solvable? If yes, how do I solve it?

Comment: What version of MariaDB? 10.2+ or older?

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting?

Comment: You need MariaDB 10.2.x or newer for your query to work. Just tried in 10.0 (failed), then in 10.3 (worked). Upgrade.

Comment: What is the problem?!? (That subquery is unnecessary.)

Comment: The assignment says "MariaDB >= 10.1" and I'm using 10.1 currently

Comment: I updated to latest MariaDB and it works. Like @TheImpaler said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL historically (and hence MariaDB) does not allow subqueries in the `FROM`.  Happily, you don't need one:

```
CREATE VIEW overbook_future_flights AS
    SELECT fe.FlightNo, fe.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC,
           ?.ICAO_Code_Origin, ?.ICAO_Code_Destination, fe.PlaneID,
           p.NoOfSeats,
           SUM(r.NoReservedSeats) as NoOfReservedSeats
    FROM reservation r JOIN
         flightexecution fe
         ON fe.FlightNo = r.FlightNo AND
         fe.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC = r.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC JOIN
         plane p
         ON fe.PlaneID = p.PlaneID
    WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP < DepartureDateAndTimeUTC
    GROUP BY fe.FlightNo, fe.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC,
             ?.ICAO_Code_Origin, ?.ICAO_Code_Destination, fe.PlaneID,
             p.NoOfSeats
    HAVING NoOfreservedSeats > p.NoOfSeats;
```

Fill in the appropriate alias for the `?`.  I may have the wrong tables for some that I guessed at.

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all column names with the appropriate alias.
- All unaggregated columns should be in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Of course... I didn't realize it could be simplified.